# Get DOMElement with specific text PHP / XPath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

In PHP, i want to get all `DOMElement` containing a given text.

I get `DOMText` when `$xpath->query("//text()[contains(., 'My String')]")`, but which query must i perform for getting `DOMElement` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use**:

```
(//*[text()
      [contains(., 'My String')]
   ]
 )[1]
```

This selects the first element in the XML document that has a text node child that contains the string `"My String"`.

If it is guaranteed that only one such element exist, the above expression can be simplified to:

```
//*[text()
      [contains(., 'My String')]
   ]
```

If the elements you are looking for are guaranteed to have just a single text-node child, this expression can be simplified to:

```
(//*[contains(., 'My String')])[1]
```

respectively:

```
//*[contains(., 'My String')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a path like `//text()[contains(., 'My String')]/..`.

Comment: Martin, usually there is an expression that doesn't contain reverse axis.