# How to run a quote search on a paragraph, and return the specific sentence containing the quote

Tags: php, regex

I'm completely new to regular expressions, and I've run into a problem.

```
$paragraph = '<text start="90" dur="4">hello world</text><text start="94" dur="5">hello humans</text>

$quote = 'hello world';
```

I want to check that $paragraph contains $quote, then return the quote's parent element node. In this case, the result would be:

```
<text start="90" dur="4">hello world</text>
```

Any ideas on how should I go about solving this?

Comment: First, let's remove the problem of trying to parse HTML with regex since that's just an invented problem. Second, let's clearly define what is meant by ___full sentence___ in this context. Does full sentence mean the parent node of the HTML in this case?

Comment: Yes. 'Full sentence' includes the <text> tags.

Comment: i'd suggest take a look at `DOMDocument` and `xpath` instead, start googling. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689579/get-domelement-with-specific-text-php-xpath

Comment: You can find that `$quote` is in `$paragraph` with `strpos`. I'd re-write the PHP example though because your description doesn't match that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can merely include `$quote` in the regex string, and type the opening/closing tags literally like this:

```
$regex = "<text start=\"[0-9]+\" dur=\"[0-9]+\">" . $quote . "<\\/text>";
```

Comment: Please warn me about syntax errors if there's any. I can't even say `Hello, World!` in PHP and I had to take a look at PHP's documentation just to write this code that concatenates a few strings.

Answer (score -1):

```
$paragraph = '<text start="90" dur="4">hello world</text><text start="94" dur="5">hello humans</text>';
$quote = 'hello world';

preg_match ("/<.*?$quote.*?>/", $paragraph, $return);
$to_print = print_r($return, true);
echo htmlspecialchars($to_print);
```

What this does is it captures everything from '<' to $quote to '>'. This means that if your quote is between p, div, span, etc. It will capture them as well.

.*? is lazy, meaning it'll capture everything until it reads the first instance of $quote, then it captures everything else until it captures the first instance of '>', after which it returns.